# unable to add new mode to cloud9 ide

Tags: cloud9-ide

so, I've created a new mymode.js and mymode_highlight_rules.js , and put these files into the ***ace/lib/ace/mode*** directory

I've restarted cloud9 but the option is not there in the language selection

what am I doing wrong ? do I also need to add / update something else somewhere else ? ;)

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are adding mode to ace you need to add caption and extensions to https://github.com/c9/core/blob/master/node_modules/ace/lib/ace/ext/modelist.js#L68

You can also create a cloud9 plugin as described at http://cloud9-sdk.readme.io/v0.1/docs/modes

Comment: so I've created this plugin - how do I install it ?

Comment: You can run `c9 publish` to create a public plugin and then `c9 install your.plugin.name` to install you can also copy folder to ~/.c9/plugins and run `c9 build --devel` to use it before publishing publicly.

Comment: to use c9 command you might need to install it with `npm install  -g c9`.